# mutual information python significance levels

Tags: python, dependencies, data-analysis, entropy

I have a dataset of 21 variables and 75 datapoints/rows. I am trying to investigate the mutual information between each pair of variables and I am quite newbie in statistics. I have used the mutual_info_score function in sklearn.metrics and this returns a number that is more than 0. How do I know which values of the value of mutual_info_score reflect dependency. For example how do you know whether to only explore the values of 1 and above, or 2 and above etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mutual information is a measure.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score

np.random.seed(42)
label_true = np.random.randint(0, 5, 75)
label_predict = np.random.randint(0, 5, 75)
print(mutual_info_score(label_true, label_predict))
```

Even with two independent random labels, you will see non-zero mutual information,

```
0.117333093974
```

What you would like to explore is using a null hypothesis test -- whether two variables are dependent or not. (null hypothesis == independence)

You may use a test for independence, e.g. chi2 in scikit-learn,

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

statsitic, p_val = chi2(label_true[:, None], label_predict[:, None])
if p_val < 0.05:
    print('dependent')
else:
    print('independent')
```

For all pairs of variables,

```
import itertools

data = np.random.randint(0, 5, (75, 21))
p_value_matrix = np.zeros((21, 21))
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(21), 2):
    _, p_val = chi2(data[:, i][:, None], data[:, j][:, None])
    p_value_matrix[i, j] = p_value_matrix[j, i] = p_val

    if p_val < 0.05:
        print('possibly dependent: {} -- {}'.format(i, j))
```

Note that, 0.05 is an arbitrary (but widely used) threshold to **reject** the null hypothesis. If resulting p-value is larger than threshold, we **cannot reject** the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what the first bit is doing, just finding the mutual information score between the two sets of variables. However, the rest seems to use the chi squared test as the test of dependence, but I was meaning to use the mutual information as a measure of dependence, as some sort of cut off point if that makes sense. I don't understand how the last bit for all pairs of variables are using mutual information?

Comment: Secondly I am having the problem of adding my dataset into the final section and replacing it with your "data" variable because my data isn't just integer values.

Comment: 1. any cut off will be arbitrary. BTW, if you can justify your choice of cut off, there is no problem with using such. 2. If you have a specific type of data, you can explore independence tests that support such kind of data. For example, you can checkout `HSIC` (Hilbert-Schimidt Independence Criterion) where you can define closeness between two values. If you are okay, you may just use (absolute value of) Pearson's correlation coefficient, etc.